# How to perform load test for confluence using the grinder tool?

Tags: load-testing, confluence, grinder

We are using confluence `5.7.3` version and we need to perform load test on our `confluence` instance.

I have recorded a script using the `grinder tool` and replay after error fixing.

Now there are no errors in my script but it doesn’t work.

How can I perform this test? What are the areas need to be considered when recording a script?

Answer (score 0):

Confluence is a widely used and accepted software and you dont need to load test it.It is license based with fixed number of logons so wont get much out of it.  If you are trying to learn grinder/load testing best approach will be to create a test application with a simple form may be some db interactions then record that script and scale it with increasing number of threads and see where it goes.